# How to count Id from a table where the data is in ranges?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `cricket_overs` having two columns like below.

```
mid overs
1   3
2   5
3   6
4   8
5   10
```

I need a count of mid where overs is in between 0-3 and 4-6 and >6.
The output should be:

```
for 0-3 overs ---count of mid 1
for 4-6 overs ---count of mid 2
for  >6 overs ---count of mid 2
--output
count
1
2
2
```

How to write a query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this, I did the following (table + data):

```
CREATE TABLE cricket_score
(
  mid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  overs INTEGER NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO cricket_score VALUES 
  (1,  3),
  (2,  5),
  (3,  6),
  (4,  8),
  (5, 10);
```

Ran the query:

```
SELECT my_count, COUNT(my_count)  AS the_score
FROM
(
  SELECT
  mid, overs, -- <<-- this line is unnecessary - helpful for understanding! 
    CASE      -- <<-- Just run the subquery on its own.
      WHEN overs BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'mid_1'
      WHEN overs BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'mid_2'
      WHEN overs > 6             THEN 'mid_3'
    END AS my_count
  FROM cricket_score
) AS STUFF
GROUP BY my_count
ORDER BY my_count;
```

And obtained the result:

```
my_count    the_score
mid_1               1
mid_2               2
mid_3               2
```

DB-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4PivVZE54AthxmubW4C5UP/1)! The DB-fiddle is for PostgreSQL - the other site, [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) was acting up (again!) and db-fiddle doesn't have MS SQ Server, but this is fairly standard stuff - should work no problem on any server!

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(*) from table where overs >=0 and overs <= 3
```

From here you should be able to expand to a complete solution. Your question showed no effort.

Comment: The result of this is a "count" of 1 - not what the OP wanted IMHO!

Comment: Maybe that should be `overs >=0`? Also, per the question, the OP was expecting three rows of output.

Comment: @RDFozz SE is not a coding service.   With any effort from there can come to a complete solution.

Comment: While I agree with you, it's perhaps appropriate to note that expanding the answer is left as an exercise for the user, as opposed to leaving it as if it were a complete answer in and of itself.